# Mysql query for the attendance register

Tags: mysql

I am planning the export of data for the attendance register, the data comes from these two db :

**Users:**

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | name   | surname |
+----+--------+---------+
| 1  | george | shish   |
| 2  | frank  | matano  |   
| 3  | test   | test    |
+----+--------+---------+
```

**reportdipendente:**

```
+-----------+---------------+------------+
| id_report | id_employee   | date       |
+-----------+---------------+------------+
| 1         | 1             | 07-09-2020 |
| 2         | 2             | 07-09-2020 |
| 3         | 2             | 06-09-2020 |
| 4         | 1             | 06-09-2020 |
+-----------+---------------+------------+
```

With that `query`:

```
SELECT id,id_employee,name,surname,GROUP_CONCAT(date) 
FROM users as u 
JOIN reportdipendente as r  
    ON u.id=r.id_employee  
WHERE r.date LIKE ? 
GROUP BY id
```

Mysql return:

```
+----+-------------+--------+---------+-----------------------+
| id | id_employee | name   | surname | date                  |
+----+-------------+--------+---------+-----------------------+
| 1  | 1           | george | shish   | 06-09-2020,07-09-2020 |
| 2  | 2           | frank  | matano  | 06-09-2020,07-09-2020 |
+----+-------------+--------+---------+-----------------------+
```

Is all ok, but how i can print users nr 3 too? because he don't have any record in second `db`

Another details:

1. i use like with param ex. `'%09-2020%'`
2. date is `varchar`

Comment: What are you passing here - r.date LIKE ?

Comment: If you need ALL users (i.e. ALL rows from a table) you must use OUTER JOIN (in your query - LEFT JOIN). Do not forget that all conditions by right table must be placed in ON clause.

Comment: Months and year like`'%09-2020%'`

Comment: So your date field is a varchar datatype (or some other string type)?

Comment: Varchar yes, i update question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, 
       COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(r.id_employee), '') id_employee, 
       u.name, 
       u.surname, 
       COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(r.date), '') date
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN reportdipendente as r  
     ON u.id=r.id_employee  
    AND r.date LIKE ? 
GROUP BY u.id, 
         u.name, 
         u.surname
```

Comment: I get an error - does only_full_group_by need to be set?manual says 'ANY_VALUE(arg)

This function is useful for GROUP BY queries when the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value which is nicely open to interpretation

Comment: In localhost i have an error '_FUNCTION dbname.ANY_VALUE does not exist_'

Comment: @SimoneRossaini If so then specify precise MySQL version. *does only_full_group_by need to be set?* Disabling this SQL mode is MySQL extension. And I do not recommend to use this extension strongly - it may be a source of logical errors non-detection.

Comment: i will update localhost version with liveserver so is not a problem. another suggest i need to add another condition if level of users is 2, i try to add after `ON u.level=2` but query catch all result to why?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini The condition placed into ON clause affects on joining (if it fails then left table row will be taken but right table row will not be attached) whereas the condition placed into WHERE clause affects on output (if it fails the whole final row will not be selected). it seems that you must put this condition into WHERE, not into ON.

Comment: You're right it works and it works even without ANY_VALUE